# My red eared slider's shell suddenly get soft

Tags: health, turtles

I have 3 month old red eared slider, I observed him yesterday, if we gently press his shell, it's getting pressed, his shell became soft, it's clearly visible and we can see with the naked eye that shell goes down when we press him.

Please help me, I am worried about my baby red eared slider.

Comment: please give more details about your setup,what type/size of tank do you have-basking area and types of lighting-what types of food-do you give any suplements-how often do you change water in your tank-have you tested the water-what is the temparature in your tank/water-any filtration.

Comment: Good that you care about the health of your turtle! There are many reasons for the shell to get soft (food, light, waters quality, infection). Because of that we need more information to eliminate that ones, that your settings avoid successful.

Comment: Maybe you find some helpfull information in this question: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26456/shell-of-turtle